# verilog assignment results in undefined 'X' output -- why?

Tags: verilog, assign

I know VHDL, and just learning verilog.  I'm trying to do a simple assignment with bit shift, and I get undefined 'X' in the result.  I don't understand why.  This is in simulation with Xilinx ISim software.

This assignment:

```
assign dout = $signed(data_out >>> shift_bits);
```

Results in 'X' wherever a '1' should be.  For example, if data_out = '00001100', and shift_bits = 1, dout will = '00000XX0'.

Below is the module definition and the assignment operation:

```
module SensorINV(
    input clk,
     input [23:0] din,
     input idv,
     input [4:0] shift_bits,
     output [23:0] dout,
     output reg odv
    );


reg [47:0] data_out = 0;        // initialize the output
assign dout = $signed(data_out >>> shift_bits);
// assign dout = data_out[44:21];   // this didn't work either

reg [1:0] state = 0;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    case (state)
        0   :   begin       // waiting for new data
            ...
        end
        1   :   begin
            ...
            data_out <= data_out + temp1_w;
            state <= 2;
        end
        2   :   begin
            ...
            state <= 0;
        end
        default :   state <= 0;
    endcase
end
```

Comment: Could be because of the different widths of data_out and dout.  Also not sure why you're taking some middle 24 bits (in your commented out line).  You could maybe try `assign dout = $signed(data_out >>> shift_bits)[UB:LB]`.  Also why is data_out a reg instead of a wire? Is there a synchronous block you're not showing us?

Comment: Without more code, I would assume it has to do with the `reg [47:0] data_out = 0;` line, which is setting up a continuous assign for `data_out` to value `48'd0`. As such, whenever you try to assign a value of 1 to any bits of `data_out`, you get `1'bx` instead. Try removing the `= 0;` part and see if you code works now.

Comment: @mstbaum, yes data_out is in a synchronous block, i posted more code to show.

Comment: @Unn, the data_out = 0 line I believe is just initialization value, not a continuous assign.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @ScottC In theory, for type `reg` it should be an initialization. If it were a net, it would be treated as a continuous assignment (ie `wire [47:0] data_out = 0` would be a continuous assignment). I think its possible this tool is doing that even though I think you are right that it shouldnt be. I wasnt able to find what the LRM says about variable types being set at declaration so Im not 100% sure on what the behavior of `reg [47:0] data_out = 0;` is strictly defined as. Still worth a short removing the initialization and seeing what happens for the simulator.

Comment: @Unn, turns out you had the right idea, and my problem is now resolved.  The line `reg [47:0] data_out = 0;` is correct for initialization, however in the next module up (not shown), I was assigning  `wire [47:0] dout = 0`, which is a continuous assignment which generated a conflict when dout attempted to be non-zero.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ScottC glad you found the issue; it did seem like a continuous assignment error somewhere :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turned out to be conflicting drivers of `dout`, only one of which was shown in the code above.  In the next module up, where this one was instantiated (not shown), I had a line like this:

```
wire [23:0] dout = 0;
```

This created a continuous assignment, not an initialization value.  This conflict didn't show up in simulation until I tried to make `dout` non-zero.  If it were a register `reg`, it would be an initialization value, but in this case it was a wire.  Got rid of the continuous assign = 0, and problem solved.